# How can i find item in an array just appear 2 times with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
[ 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7 ]
```

How can i find item in an array just appear 2 times with javascript?

Like this case: just return 2 and 5

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just iterate through the array and make a map `A` where `A[i]` is the count of `i` in your array. Then (or even better - during calculation), you can easily output those, which appeared twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a count object.

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7],
    count = {},
    items;

data.forEach(function (a) {
    count[a] = (count[a] || 0) + 1;
});
items = Object.keys(count).filter(function (k) { return count[k] === 2; });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(items, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: thanks! Nina,  i haven't learn any about object.keys() and object.filter() yet, I will keep learning :D

Comment: @ByerGallagher, i added some more information about the methods.

Comment: Thank you!^_^ You're Awesome